# Subdividing/filtering a dataframe with two row-wise parameters in list

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, purrr

I need to filter/subdivide a dataframe considering two parameters (for exclusion) that are in a dbl_df list (39 obs; below are the first ones to exemplify).

```
parameters <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), V2 = c(2018, 2019, 
2020, 2019)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Both V1 and V2 are contained in the df to be filtered.

```
df <- structure(list(V_L = c("AS", "AS", "EU", "AF", "AS", "AM", "EU", 
"EU"), V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "C"), V2 = c(2018, 
2019, 2020, 2019, 2021, 2019, 2019, 2020), value = c(12, 13, 
14, 11, 8, 16, 14, 20)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(V_L = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), V1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), V2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), value = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = "\t"), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x000001f92fdddf90>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df_filtered:

[image]

I believe I have come close with help in other questions here on the forum, however I believe with the map_df function I am looking at the end of a bind rows.

```
map_df(parameters, ~ df %>% filter(!V1 == .x[2] & !V2 == .x[2]))
```

Can anyone troubleshoot or suggest another more operational proposal.

Comment: Cant understand what do you want. Subdividing or filtering? Please put example of what do you expect and exapmle of the data you have, in reproducible manner (that is, in R)

Comment: I put the minimum data structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading data (the given `df` didn't load for me without tweaking)

```
parameters <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), V2 = c(2018, 2019, 
2020, 2019)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

df <- structure(list(V_L = c("AS", "AS", "EU", "AF", "AS", "AM", "EU", 
"EU"), V1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "C"), V2 = c(2018, 
2019, 2020, 2019, 2021, 2019, 2019, 2020), value = c(12, 13, 
14, 11, 8, 16, 14, 20)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

---

I'd suggest using an anti join, which will return all rows from `df` which do not match to a row of `parameters`.

```
dplyr::anti_join(df, parameters)

Joining, by = c("V1", "V2")
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  V_L   V1       V2 value
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 AS    A      2021     8
2 AM    D      2019    16
3 EU    B      2019    14
4 EU    C      2020    20
```